# How do I change what controller is used in MK8?

Tags: mario-kart-8

I just started playing Mario Kart 8 and I can't figure out how to be able to use the Nunchuck for Player 1's controller.  I can use the pad just fine, but I don't even see an option menu for setting which controller I want to use.  Can I only use the nunchuck in multiplayer or something?

Comment: I just tried plugging in/unplugging the Nunchuck from the main menu (Single Player/Multiplayer/etc.).  It prompts for you to press A on the controller you want to use, and picks it up just fine. If that's not working for you, I suspect you have a faulty Nunchuk or connection between your controller and Nunchuk.

Comment: @Mag: I suspect that he entered the menu using the Gamepad (because that's what he had to use to get into the game) then started to look into where to change the controller

Comment: Ah! I misunderstood - thought he was saying the Wii Remote was working but the Nunchuk added to it was not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The controller used by the first player is the controller that was used to pass the title screen, before the menu where you can select "Single Player", "Multiplayer", etc. You can pass this title screen with any kind of supported controller.

If the wrong controller has been used, you can back out to the title screen with the B button and start again with the correct controller without needing to reset the game entirely.